# What's the easiest way to get 3D-positional data of galaxies

Tags: galaxy, data-analysis

Is there a database with cartesian coordinates (x, y, z) of galaxies? I only need positional data and calculating that using degrees and redshift for all galaxies could take a while and would be complicated.

Comment: Check VizieR...

Comment: The speed of coordinate transformation is no problem if your code preprocesses them.